# Updating specific fields based on matching against data already in the table

Tags: sql

I have a table that is composed of the following fields:
Location_ID, User_ID, Last_Name, First_Name, Birthday, SSN

I am trying to merge it with another table that contains the same schema. However, the caveat is that it is possible for users to exist in both tables and with different User_ID's due to different versions of the application. If I were to simply merge them I would get duplicates, where one Last_Name, First_Name, Birthday, SSN could have two User_ID's associated with it.

What I'd like to do is merge my new dataset into the old one, matching on Last_Name, First_Name, Birthday, and SSN, and only adding the user with the new User_ID if there is not an entry that matches those previous four constraints. I'm at a loss as to the proper way to do this. Any suggestions?

Comment: Please post the code that you hare having difficult with in the question itself.

Comment: have to agree with @FreshPrinceOfSO as we need to know how you're trying to attempt what you're doing first before we can help you with it....gives everyone a better starting point to work with.

Answer (score 0):

I would try the follwing. For each record you want to insert/update, first check if there's a row with matching fields (First_Name, Last_Name etc..), if there's a row that matches it, run your update command, else insert.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach using standard SQL:

```
insert into t1(User_ID, Last_Name, First_Name, Birthday, SSN)
    select User_ID, Last_Name, First_Name, Birthday, SSN
    from t2
    where not exists (select 1
                      from t1
                      where t1.Last_Name = t2.Last_Name and
                            t1.First_Name = t2.First_Name and
                            t1.Birthday = t2.Birthday and
                            t1.SSN = t2.SSN
                     );
```

Having provided the SQL, I suspect that it won't really work in this case.  Typically, when you have a problem like this, you also have slightly different formats for things in the two tables.  For instance, one might have a first initial and the other a complete first name.  Or one might have a suffix on the last name preceded by a comma, and the other with no comma.